# How to emulate returning arbitrary values from functions in bash?

Tags: bash, function, shell, command-line

Bash functions are just statements and they don't return values. Can anyone share best practice on writing functions that return values in bash?

Let's say I've a function that joins two strings:

```
function JoinStrings {
    returnValue="$1$2"
}
```

How do I reuse this function in my code? How do I get `returnValue` to be returned to caller? Should I just use it as a global after this function call? That leads to many errors with global variables everywhere... How to achieve code reuse in bash?

Comment: "Function" is really a poor choice of names for this bit of shell; "subroutine" would have been better, since they don't actually return a value. (Even `return` just sets the exit status, whose semantics have more in common with an exception than a return value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `echo` to "return" an arbitrary value:

```
join_strings() {
    echo "$1$2"
}

cat="cat"
dog="dog"
catdog=$(join_strings $cat $dog)
echo $catdog
# catdog
```

Comment: That is very cool - I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just output the value.

```
function JoinStrings {
    echo "$1$2"
}
JoinStrings a b         #ab
x=$(JoinStrings a bc)   #x is now abc
```

Comment: Wow that is nice! Thanks!